# socket.io: crypto.js error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I had a very simple example using Socket.IO that is not working anymore after switching to Socket.IO 0.6.1 (installed with npm) and node.JS 0.5.0-pre (without ssl).

transports/websocket.js:128:22 tries to  use crypto.js:101 [return new Hash(hash)] which fails with "undefined is not a function".

In the current state of development I don't care about encryption/security issues. This happens when trying to connect(). Does anybody has an idea why this fails?

Answer (score 0):

transports/websocket.js:128:22

```
var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
```

You need crypto for properly form websockets 'handshake' request, so you CAN'T make it without ssl (or inplementing your own `md5` functional)